# unable to view the line on swift

Tags: swift, xcode6, cgrectmake

I am trying to add a horizontal line that starts from left side of the screen to the right. But the line isn't visible.

```
let horizontalLine : CGRect = CGRectMake(45, height-50, 45, 55)
var testView : UIView = UIView(frame: horizontalLine)
self.view.addSubview(testView)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try with this

```
let horizontalLine : CGRect = CGRectMake(45, 100-50, 45, 55)
//check value of height. this height>=(status bar height(20)+navigation bar height (44))
    var testView : UIView = UIView(frame: horizontalLine)
    testView.backgroundColor = UIColor.redColor()
    self.view.addSubview(testView)
```